# Integrate OpenCart for Existing Application

Tags: opencart, shopping-cart

I have existing website and I want to add shopping cart functionality to my website.

I tried to use OpenCart. After installation the website shows the OpenCart default page.
How can I use my existing web page along with OpenCart?

Comment: OC is based On **MVCL** if your application is as such it may work but will require lot of coding its better to build OC as such :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to integrate Opencart with a CMS such as Wordpress, I would recommend that you install Opencart on subdomain.
For example:
First you install Wordpress on domain `www.yourdomain.com` then your opencart is on `shop.yourdomain.com`. At Wordpress, make a menu link to your opencart, and at opencart make a link to wordpress (main site).
Hope it help you| Cheers ^_^